# Forces and Vectors

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, vectors

This questions regards to doing force calculation using vectors. This image here should display my problem [image].

In basic newtonian physics, the normal force = force of gravity * cosine (angle of inclination). $$F_N = F_G \times \cos{\theta}$$

To be clearer:

$$F_N = (x_G, y_G) \times \cos{\theta}$$ $$F_N = (0, 9.8) \times \cos{\theta}$$ $$F_N = (0, 9.8\cos{\theta})$$

The problem is not calculating this value but representing it as a 2D vector format. How is the **x-component** of $F_N = 0$, when the diagram (according to the direction of where the $F_N$ is pointing) clearly shows that the **x-component** should have a value? I believe I have messed up my calculations. Could someone please help me? Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

The **x-component** of $F_N$ should have a value other than $0$, otherwise, if it was = 0, it would be pointing straight up or down. This does not seem to be occurring in my calculations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you got wrong answer (x-component of $F_N$ = 0) is that when you worte      "$F_N = F_G \times \cos{\theta}$" and calculated further, you actually assumed that two vectors $\vec{F_N}$ and $\vec{F_G}$ are collinear, but they are not! 
The expression you wrote - "$F_N = F_G \times \cos{\theta}$" is just a scalar expression! 
With this, you can only calculate $\mathbf{magnitude}$ of $\vec{F_N}$. 
Knowing magnitude, if you want x-, y- components of $\vec{F_N}$ , you can easily calculate them. $$------------$$
Or if someone still insist upon you to calculate $\vec{F_N}$ using vector operations, you can try this: 
unit normal vector of the surface (downward) :  $\vec{n}=(sin\theta , -cos\theta)$.
then projection of $\vec{F_G}$ onto $\vec{n}$ is : $(\vec{F_G} \cdot \vec{n}) \cdot \vec{n}   $ .
and then the $\vec{F_N}$ is : $-(\vec{F_G} \cdot \vec{n}) \cdot \vec{n}   $ .

(where $\vec{F_G} \cdot \vec{n}$ is a dot product of two vectors)

Comment: Welcome to PSE! Note that "check my work" questions are off topic, so one should flag to close the question rather than providing answers to them.

Answer (score 2):

> In basic newtonian physics, the normal force = force of gravity * cosine (angle of inclination).

That is not correct.  In your problem, the **magnitude** of the normal force on the block will be equal to the **magnitude** of weight of the block times the cosine of the inclination angle. (While that happens often, it is not always true.)

The direction of the normal force is **not** the direction of the weight.